# Process running over multiple server blades? Possible?

Tags: server, operating-system

I don't know much about how data centers work, i know there are server raks filled with server blades[machines cpu,ram...] all interconnected through fiber links.
So, what i want to know, is it possible for a process made of N threads to run on more than one machines at a time?
 if yes, is the OS responsable for it or...?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot guys... >.>
Got the answer i wanted..

http://www.cloudbus.org/papers/SSI-CCWhitePaper.pdf

```
“A single system image (SSI) is the
property of a system that hides the
heterogeneous and distributed nature of
the available resources and presents them
to users and applications as a single
unified computing resource.”
```